# Hiding a text input without making it `type="hidden"`

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

### What I have

I'm using the `FormController` to [create inputs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-text-inputs). A specific input will be frequently updated by Javascript for internal purposes and I want it hidden. In this case, I can't use `type="hidden"`, instead it needs to be `type="text"` so that it won't be checked by the [form tampering prevention](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html#form-tampering-prevention) when submitted.

### What I tried

- Adding `'hidden' => true` to `$this->Form->create()` options works if the whole form needs to be hidden. That exact attribute doesn't seem to be working for individual inputs though, created using both `$this->Form->input()` and `$this->Form->control()`
- For a specific input, first thing that comes to mind is adding `'style' => 'display:none'` to its options, but that does not seem like a clean CakePHP-way solution
- I think I've seen someone mention a way to do exactly that here. I think it was an attribute you'd add to the options. I searched around my answers and comments, using both this site and Google, but found nothing.

Please advise!

Comment: may i know what exactly you want to do?you are trying to hide the form or what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a hidden input and make it exempt from form security in case required, either by unlocking the field via the `unlockField()` method:

```
$this->Form->unlockField('field_name');
echo $this->Form->hidden('field_name');
```

or by passing `false` or `'skip'` for the `secure` option:

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('field_name', ['secure' => false]);
```

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('field_name', [
    'secure' => \Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::SECURE_SKIP
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Working with SecurityComponent > unlockField()](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#Cake%5CView%5CHelper%5CFormHelper::unlockField)**

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Will `unlockField` or `'secure' => false` ignore only the value, or the whole input (i.e. it can be missing from the post data)?

Comment: @aexl It will completely ignore it, ie it will neither check for the fields existence, nor for its content.

Comment: I wasn't sure but I guess that's why I didn't go that route initially. So then is there any straightforward way to have an input remain hidden but act as a text input without CSS `display:none` trickery? I guess the answer is no, but just confirming. Thanks

Comment: @aexl Maybe I misunderstood you question, what I'm saying is that it will be ignored by the security component, it will of course not be missing from the POST data if it's submitted with the form.